# Long response time in anonymous middleware

Tags: node.js, express, nestjs, datadog

I'm using NestJS (with Express Server) for a project and trying to optimize the performance on some of the endpoints. Using Datadog I noticed that about 83% of the response time of all endpoints is spent in an anonymous middleware. Does anyone know what middleware this is and why it's taking this long?

[image: Usage stats]

I suspect that it has to do with the framework itself due to the similar unanswered question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63778644/annotating-an-annonymus-middleware-in-newrelic-in-a-nestjs-app).

Comment: If I had to hazard a guess, it's your enhancers + controller + service. It's probably how Nest runs all of the requests under the hood, _technically_ as an Express middleware

Comment: Sounds like something to ask the NestJS folks about, over on https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues, after searching their issues for things that might be similar, before posting to Stackoverflow?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Their Github issue tracker says to post questions like this to their Stack Overflow tag...

Comment: That is very unfortunate, and seems to ignore that labels and projects exist for a reason on github, but: in that case my comment does not apply.

Answer (score 3):

[You're welcome to go look through the source code yourself](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/master/packages/core/router/router-explorer.ts#L147), but generally my comment is correct. Nest binds all route handlers and enhancers (guards, interceptors, pipes, and filters) as a large anonymous function, in a very abstract way (does the same thing for Fastify as far as I can tell).

Answer (score 0):

jumping to the party late,  but after prolonged debugging, I found that all middleware that are defined like so:

```
export class AppModule {
configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer): void {
    consumer.apply(HttpContextMiddleWare).forRoutes('*');

    }
}
```

will get the anonymous name tag since the middleware is wrapped like Jay said, I wanted to add my answer here since he pointed out that it can be a service or something else, while it is a middleware.

edit:
one solution that I found to the problem is to set the middleware globally in the main.ts:

```
app.use(setLoggingMiddleware(config, await 
app.resolve(Logger)));
```

and the actual middleware looks like this:

```
export function setLoggingMiddleware(configService: ConfigService, logger: Logger) {
//config service and logger can be resolved from app context in main.ts
return function loggingMiddleware(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
   //body of middleware

    next();
};
```

}

please note that there is a drawback to which I am still looking for a solution. with this method, you can not set the middleware to a specific path or verb, so this way will work only for either middleware with no DI or on all paths, but not both.